# Make Selectable True for only given date range in React Big Calendar

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am using React Big Calendar. By Default selectable true make the whole calendar selectable but I want to make only selectable true of given time and change the background color of that time range in the calendar. I am not willing to create event. Just make selectable true of given times.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that may help you to disable some dates , in my case , I needed to disable unavailability events, so I used  `selectable="ignoreEvents"`

```
         `<BigCalendar
            selectable="ignoreEvents"
            localizer={localizer}
            events={events} 
            views={allViews}  
            step={60}
            showMultiDayTimes
            defaultDate={new Date()}
            defaultView={BigCalendar.Views.WEEK}
            style={{height: "90vh" }}
            resources={resourceMap}
            resourceIdAccessor="resourceId"
            resourceTitleAccessor="resourceTitle"
            onSelectSlot={this.handleSelect}
            eventPropGetter={(this.eventStyleGetter)}
          />`
```

use `eventPropGetter` to style you events